# Error en Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

Estimados tengo este método:

```
  /**
     * @Security("has_role('ROLE_BONOS_FACTURADO_LISTAR') or has_role('ROLE_IDDQD')")
     * @Route("/admin/bono/facturados/descargar/{uuid}", name="bonos_facturados_descargar_pdf")
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function downloadPDF($uuid) {
        $response = new Response();
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
        $fullpath = $this->get('kernel')->getProjectDir(). "/../web/bonos/" . $uuid . ".pdf";
        $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;filename="' . $uuid . '.pdf');
        $content = @file_get_contents($fullpath);
        if ($content == false) {
            $this->addFlashError('No se encontro la factura');
            return $this->redirectToRoute('bonos_facturados');
        }
        $response->setContent($content);
        return $response;
    }
```

Y me esta arrojando este error:

> Service "kernel" not found: even though it exists in the app's container, the container inside "App\Controller\BonoController" is a smaller service locator that only knows about the "doctrine", "form.factory", "http_kernel", "parameter_bag", "request_stack", "router", "security.authorization_checker", "security.csrf.token_manager", "security.token_storage", "serializer", "session", "templating" and "twig" services. Try using dependency injection instead.

Answer (score 0):

No puedes obtener el servicio `kernel` desde el container asociado a los controladores. Si por alguna razón necesitas hacer uso de él, inyéctalo explícitamente usando el inyector de dependencias. No obstante, si lo que necesitas es el directorio raíz de la aplicación, prueba a consultar el parámetro en cuestión, siempre y cuando tu controlador extienda de `AbstractController`

```
$projectDir = $this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir');
$fullpath = $projectDir . "/../web/bonos/" . $uuid . ".pdf";
```